# update_post_meta not working?

Tags: post-meta

The value is not updated when using the following code:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'updatethumb' );

function updatethumb( $post_id ) {

    //verify post is not a revision
    if ( !wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {

        //$thumb = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'thumb', false);
        $ft=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'thumb', true);
        //echo '<script>alert("'.$ft.'")</script>';
        update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'thumb', 'testxxx'); 

    }

}
```

Why is that?

Comment: Why do you do this? `get_the_ID` does only work (as expected) within the Loop. You already have the post ID given in `$post_id`...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure about what you want to do...
Maybe it's this:

```
add_action('save_post', 'update_thumb');

function update_thumb($post_id) {

    //verify post is not a revision
    if (! wp_is_post_revision($post_id)) {

        $new_value = 'testxxx';
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'thumb', $new_value); 

    }

}
```